# pandas isn't recognising my datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I exported this from a postgres table as a tab-separated csv, like so:

```sql
\copy (select * from mytable) to 'labels.csv' csv DELIMITER E'\t' header
```

Which is (file head)

```py
user_id  session_id   start_time           mode
  2       715      2016-04-01 01:07:49+01   car
  2       716      2016-04-01 03:09:53+01   car
  2      1082      2016-04-02 13:05:16+01   car
  2      1090      2016-04-02 15:16:32+01   car
```

I read this into pandas and wanted to remove timezone info, this way:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('labels.csv', sep='\t',parse_dates=['start_time']) 
df['start_time'] = df['start_time'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

But gives the error:

```py
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

`df.head()` gives:

```py
user_id  session_id     start_time              mode
0    2         715  2016-04-01 01:07:49+01:00     car
1    2         716  2016-04-01 03:09:53+01:00     car
2    2        1082  2016-04-02 13:05:16+01:00     car
3    2        1090  2016-04-02 15:16:32+01:00     car
4    2        1601  2016-04-04 13:56:13+01:00     foot
```

However,

```py
df.info()
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------               --------------  ----- 
 0   user_id              5374 non-null   int64 
 1   session_id           5374 non-null   int64 
 2   start_time           5374 non-null   object
 3   transportation_mode  5374 non-null   object
dtypes: int64(3), object(2)
```

Comment: It seems the error appears in the second line of the code. Could you show what `df` is after the first line is executed?

Comment: added details in question edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the docs for [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **`parse_dates`** : ***bool or list of int or names or list of lists or dict, default False***
>
> ...
>
> If a column or index cannot be represented as an array of datetimes, say because of an unparsable value or a mixture of timezones, the column or index will be returned unaltered as an object data type. For non-standard datetime parsing, use `pd.to_datetime` after `pd.read_csv`. To parse an index or column with a mixture of timezones, specify `date_parser` to be a partially-applied [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `utc=True`. See [Parsing a CSV with mixed timezones](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-csv-mixed-timezones) for more.

You likely have an unparseable date in your data. Try to coerce to datetime after you read using [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), to cause an error on the bad value, as this will raise errors on bad values by default:

```py
df["start_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_time"])
```

Once you identify the issue, you can then handle the value in your code. Something like:

```py
# explicitly handle known invalid values
df["start_time"] = df["start_time"].replace({"--": pd.NaT})
df["start_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_time"])
```